# Is it okay to set IndexPath for TableView using IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, swift4, indexpath

I'm trying to set indexPath for tableview to scroll to particular position.
Instead of IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), I used collection view IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0.

It's working as expected, just want to confirm will it make any difference.

> let indexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
>
> vs
>
> let indexPath : IndexPath = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)

Below is my code snippet:

```
 let indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
 tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: Does it work if you use a different number than 0?

Comment: Yes @Sweeper.. It works for numbers greater than zero as well.